# Django app.py removes underscore in Config

Tags: python, django, naming-conventions

PEP 8 says "Modules should have short, all-lowercase names. Underscores can be used in the module name if it improves readability. Python packages should also have short, all-lowercase names, although the use of underscores is discouraged."

I am working on an educational program which could, ultimately, have many lessons. Sometimes one app could deliver thousands of lessons (i.e. spelling), but still, there could be many apps. Underscores in lower case names for readability seems essential.

When I use an underscore in an app name,  such as clockwise_counter, "python manage.py startapp clockwise_counter" removes the underscore in constructing the class name in apps.py. The class name becomes 
"class ClockwiseCounterConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'clockwise_counter'"

This caused me a lot of confusion until I learned to copy the apps.py class name into the INSTALLED_APPS section of settings.py by removing the underscore.

My Questions are:

1. Why are the underscores discouraged in PEP 8?  Is there really a good reason or was it just personal preference sometime in the past.
2. Am I likely to have problems using underscores in app names for readability now or in the future?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. `clockwise_counter` is the app name, but `ClockwiseCounterConfig` is a class name and therefore follows the PEP8 recommendation for classes.

Comment: Most web sites have a few pages to perhaps a few hundred pages.  An educational program delivered on the web could have ten thousand pages or even a hundred thousand pages.  Having underscores to give app names a reasonable similarity to the taxonomy of the subject would seem to make sense.  Otherwise, app names would have no relation to the subject taxonomy.

Comment: I have no idea what that has to do with anything. App configs are classes, and they are constructed from the module name in a predictable and repeatable way. In any case, the number of pages shouldn't relate to the number of classes in your app; if you have a hundred thousand classes you definitely have something very very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

That's a standard behaviour and NOT a bug. The underscore in module or package names is legal, you are thus you may put underscores in these names.

In another hand having a `Clockwise_Counter_Config` class is somehow ugly (but it works).

Ah, and the `INSTALLED_APPS` settings is a list (or sequence) of apps **package** dotted names, and not of class names.